# Mac Daemon for ActiveMQ

Tags: macos, activemq-classic, launchd

I have tried setting `ActiveMQ` daemon but have been unsuccessful so far. I can't seem to load `ActiveMQ`. Not sure what more can I do to make this work? I can start `ActiveMQ` by running command `/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq start`

In the plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apache.activemq</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>            
        <string>/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq</string>
        <string>start</string>
        <string>;</string>
        <string>--stop-cmd</string>
        <string>/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq</string>
        <string>stop</string>
        <string>;</string>
        <string>--restart-cmd</string>
        <string>/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq</string>
        <string>restart</string>
        <string>;</string>
        <string>--pid=none</string>
    </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/Library/ActiveMQ</string>
    <key>ServiceDescription</key>
    <string>ActiveMQ</string>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/activemq.stderr</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/activemq.stdout</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Result of executing the `launchctl` command

`macosx user$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/activemq.plist
com.apache.activemq: Already loaded`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run below command on terminal

```
 sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/activemq.plist
```

or

```
sudo launchctl remove com.apache.activemq
```

then

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/activemq.plist
```

Comment: Well the `load` command works. Not sure what was the difference between my load command and your load command. But anyhow I can see ActiveMQ started. So in short this solved my problem. BTW I checked, `unload` does not stop `ActiveMQ`. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @LCC From launchctl unload man page : This will also stop the job if it is running.

Comment: @Parag You are right. I removed my comments. Unloading *will* send `SIGTERM`. Should the job catch this signal `launchd` will send `SIGKILL` after `ExitTimeOut` seconds to bring it down. I assume that `activemq` is spawning a child process in a way that killing its parent does not affect its operation.

Answer (score 2):

Your .plist file looks wrong in several ways, and this may be causing at least part of the problem. First, the ProgramArguments seems to have a lot of irrelevant junk in it (maybe leftovers from using daemond?) In general, the first argument of ProgramArguments should be the path to the program you want to execute, and the rest should be its arguments. It looks to me like this is all you should have:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>            
    <string>/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq</string>
    <string>start</string>
</array>
```

Second, that "start" argument makes me think that's not the actual daemon program, but a management script that starts the daemon in the background, then exits. When you run `/Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq start` by hand, does it exit (i.e. give you a new shell prompt) and leave the daemon running in the background? launchd doesn't expect that, it expects to be running the daemon directly, so that it can monitor it and e.g. restart it if necessary. Here's the typical sequence when you tell launchd to run a starter script, rather than the actual daemon:

1. launchd runs the starter script.
2. The starter script runs the daemon in the background, then exits.
3. launchd sees that the program it was told to run has exited, and thinks to itself "OMG it's crashed! I'd better clean up the mess and restart it!"
4. In an attempt to "clean up the mess", launchd kills any leftover background processes; in this case, that means it kills the actual daemon.
5. Since launchd has been told to keep the program alive, it starts a new instance, restarting the whole sequence over and over again.

...Needless to say, this doesn't work very well. If this or something similar is happening, you have two options to fix it:

- Skip the starter script, and have launchd run the actual daemon directly. This is the better way to do it, because you get launchd's ability to monitor, restart, stop, etc the daemon.
- Use the starter script, but tell launchd not to panic when it exits. Change `KeepAlive` to false, and add `<key>AbandonProcessGroup</key><true/>`

Comment: In response to your questions. When I run it by hand it does exit after starting the daemon and shows the shell prompt. I liked the solution you proposed. Either run it as daemon directly or change the starter script. How should I set it to run as daemon directly? Not familiar with setting up daemons.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with activemq to know. What I'd recommend is looking at the starter script to see what it does. If it just runs a program in the background (i.e. with `&` at the end of the command), just do that. If it does more than that, you may have to write your own script that does the other bits, then runs the actual daemon in the foreground. BTW, it'll probably also create and/or check a PID file so it can tell if the daemon's already running; you can ignore this bit, as launchd makes that unnecessary.

Comment: If I'm reading the [activepq docs](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-StartingActiveMQ) right, the actual daemon may be /Library/ActiveMQ/bin/activemq - if so, all you'd need to do is have that path as the only element in `ProgramArguments`.

Comment: I tried by removing the `start` argument from `plist` and it failed to load. So it seems I need to have the `location of activemq` and the argument `start` to successfully execute plist.

Comment: Is there an executable at /Library/ActiveMQ/bin/activemq (note: no /macosx/ in that path)? If so, try running that. Also, take a look at the /Library/ActiveMQ/bin/macosx/activemq script and see what it actually does.

Comment: Yes there is one under just `bin`. I can try to use that. I think its good to compare whats in both the shell script under `bin/activemq` and `bin/macosx/activemq`. Will post the diff soon.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the ideas of @Gordon Davisson

but I'm calling   **activemq console** instead **activemq start**
and it is working now.

here the complete plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.13.2/bin/activemq</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.13.2/bin/activemq</string>
        <string>console</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/activemq/5.13.2/libexec/data</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```