# How to start ActiveMq on system startup in Mac OS

Tags: macos, activemq-classic, system, startup

is there any way to start activemq server automatically on system startup in Mac OS? I would like it to start whenever I start the system.

I tried to find in official document, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends how you installed it.

---

If you did the sensible thing and installed it via **homebrew**, then you can start it immediately and on all future restarts with:

```
brew services start activemq
```

This information would have been displayed to you when you installed `activemq`, but in case you forgot it, you can get it again with the following command (see last 3 lines specifically):

```
brew info activemq
```

**Sample Output**

```
activemq: stable 5.15.6
Apache ActiveMQ: powerful open source messaging server

https://activemq.apache.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/activemq.rb
==> Requirements
Required: java >= 1.7 ✔
==> Caveats
To have launchd start activemq now and restart at login:
  brew services start activemq
Or, if you don't want/need a background service you can just run:
  activemq start
```

---

If you decided to do things the hard way, and installed it from source, you will need to use `launchctl` to interact with Apple's `launchd`. An example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440619/2836621).

Comment: I have done the hard way, I installed binary and run it from console. So I will go with the example you have provided.